# ID undefined na função Auth.currentUserInfo() aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, react, amazon-aws, sdk

Olá estou usando o sdk da aws, para recuperar as informações do usuario logado estou chamando o método:

**Auth.currentUserInfo();**

Mas ele volta o objeto:

```
attributes: {
    sub: "13fd444d-2b2c-4d5c-b8b5-022fd599fd11", email_verified: true, 
    phone_number_verified: false, phone_number: "+5599999999999", 
    preferred_username: "email"
},
id: undefined,
username: "456e972da800ba06e8a22bc8a9910d4e"
```

Repare que ele retorna `id: undefined`

Porque isso acontece ? estou trabalhando com a versao: `"aws-amplify": "^1.1.18"`

link da [documentação aqui](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js)

erro que aparece ao habilitar o debug da AWS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Consegui colocando o código:

```
await (await Auth.currentCredentials()).getPromise();
```

antes de chamar o metodo Auth.currentUserInfo():

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await (await Auth.currentCredentials()).getPromise();

    const info = await Auth.currentUserInfo()
    console.log('info: ', info)
    this.setState({ info })
  }
```

Para contexto, a biblioteca tenta ler o identityId das credenciais, mas elas podem não estar prontas ainda ao chamar Auth.currentUserInfo()

Comment: Legal! isso me da um norte maior, porem ao implementar em meu código, gerou este erro: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _a.sent(...).getPromise is not a function

Comment: você tentou o: `async componentDidMount() {
  const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
  console.log('user info:', user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload)
  console.log('username:', user.username)
}`

Comment: testei, isso funciona e me retorna informacoes, porem quando uso await Auth.currentUserInfo(); ele me retorna o objt com tudo preenchido menos só o id como undefined. PS: no MAC do meu amigo funciona o mesmo código e retorna um id, nos windowns que testei volta undefined